# PowerBI. Why are my values being repeated?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following measure:

Time = CALCULATE(SUM('Time'[Actual Time]))

Depending on the origin of column Department I get different results. Why are the Hours values being repeated in my visualisation on the left?

[image: Model]

[image: Different Hours result depending on where Department column comes from]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationships only pass filters in the direction of the small arrow. You are most likely summing hours in the right (or left) table, and not seeing it filtered when using the department dimension column from the left (or right) table.

This is pretty basic, so I would recommend taking an intro course to Power BI.

Comment: Thank you @Marcus . I wanted to connect Table A (left) and Table E(right) by Department but then there are multiple instances of Department in Table A and the relationship would have to be many to many. So instead I created a bridge table Department(middle). Was this the right way to do it?
Also, the visual that is repeating the total sum in every row, I am using the Time measure from Table A(left) and Department from Table E(right). Basically, you're saying this is correct behaviour and there is no other way around it. Is this correct?

Comment: There are ways around it, for sure. But that depends on what you want to achieve. For the case in your question it appears to be sufficient to just use the Department column in your bridge table whenever you want to slice by this category.